# JSoup.connect with some requests has 403 error

Tags: java, jsoup, http-status-code-403

I try to get HTML source by `Jsoup.connect` of this page: [https://bitskins.com/?market_hash_name=SSG+08+%7C+DARK+WATER+%28Field-Tested%29&is_stattrak=0&has_stickers=0&sort_by=bumped_at&order=desc](https://bitskins.com/?market_hash_name=SSG%2008%20%7C%20DARK%20WATER%20%28Field-Tested%29&is_stattrak=0&has_stickers=0&sort_by=bumped_at&order=desc)

but, I have the error: `Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=https://bitskins.com/?market_hash_name=SSG+08+%7C+DARK+WATER+%28Field-Tested%29&is_stattrak=0&has_stickers=0&sort_by=bumped_at&order=desc`

My code is:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://bitskins.com/?market_hash_name=SSG+08+%7C+DARK+WATER+%28Field-Tested%29&is_stattrak=0&has_stickers=0&sort_by=bumped_at&order=desc")
            .data(":authority", "bitskins.com")
            .data(":method", "GET")
            .data(":path", "/?market_hash_name=SSG+08+%7C+DARK+WATER+%28Field-Tested%29&is_stattrak=0&has_stickers=0&sort_by=bumped_at&order=desc")
            .data(":scheme", "https")
            .data("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
            .data("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br")
            .data("accept-language:", "ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6")
            .data("cache-control", "max-age=0")
            .data("cookie", "__cfduid=d76231c8cccdbd5303a7d4feeb3f3a11f1466541718; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1292204706.1466541721; request_method=POST; _session_id=5dc49c7814d5087ac51f9d9da20b2680")
            .data("dnt", "1")
            .data("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1")
            .data("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")
            .post();
```

What is the problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `.data()` adds to the form data, not the header. So you need to use the appropriate methods to set the related information. Refer to below to fix your code:

To set the header:

`.header("key", "value")`

To set the form data:

`.data("key", "value")`

To set user agent:

`.userAgent("Mozilla...")`